# Improve workflow when programming/editing for html/css/js

Tags: html, css, linux, vim, workflow

My workflow is connect via ssh to a development server where I use vim. I miss the convenience of using IDE to edit html/css/javascript files to be honest.
Is there someone with a workflow as mine that can help in programming for html/css/js files e.g. to make sure there is no typo/syntax error, available properties/methods etc?

Comment: Some options to consider, X Forwarding which is bring the IDE to your local machine or Run the IDE locally and sync the files using ftp or scp. Or use version control and sync through that.

Comment: @FDinoff:The files are already under version control. For syncing the files you mean write some custom script to re-upload the files?

Comment: You can check out the plugin syntastic for checking syntax errors. https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- use your graphical environment software (like gnome, kde) to mount remote directory via sftp (part of ssh) and edit files locally using IDE,
- use sshfs and do the same thing but without help of GE parts,
- use dropbox (or anything like that) to sync data between server and your computer,
- use any available network file system (NFS, Samba, ???).

Comment: `without help of GE parts` what is GE?

Comment: graphical environment ;-)